Reading a specific value based on an indexed dataframe in rust with polars
I am trying to read a value from a dataframe based on index and column on rust. I do not know how to create an indexed dataframe. I have been unable to find much information on this. For instance, if my df was:
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ ID  ┆ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ D   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 0.0 ┆ 1.0 ┆ 2.0 ┆ 1.0 ┆ 1.0 │
│ 1.0 ┆ 2.0 ┆ 3.0 ┆ 1.0 ┆ 2.0 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘

I would want to select a value for A based on the ID.
I have tried to read the column, convert it to a series then a vector and read based on index, but have been struggling to find working documentation. I have also tried based on row and then to series etc.
Any and all help is appreciated.

Are you trying to set or retrieve the value of A?

Just to retrieve.

Using Polars expressions:
let value = df
    .lazy()
    .filter(col("ID").eq(0.))
    .select([col("A")])
    .collect()
    .unwrap()["A"]
    .f64()
    .unwrap()
    .get(0)
    .unwrap();

There are many other filters available.
